# one click two checkbox are checked

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have multiple checkbox dynamicly.if i check one checkbox or select any its should be check another checkbox is checked

```
<div class="ic_schedule mb_20"
    <div class="form-check sc_click">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="date[]" value="2023-03-02">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="timeslot[]" value="18" id="18">
        <label class="form-check-label d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center" for="18">
            <span> 11:00 AM - 01:00 PM (2 Hour)</span>
            <span class="ic_date_time">02, Thu</span>
        </label>
    </div>
<div class="form-check sc_click">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="date[]" value="2023-03-02">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="timeslot[]" value="18" id="18">
        <label class="form-check-label d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center" for="18">
            <span> 11:00 AM - 01:00 PM (2 Hour)</span>
            <span class="ic_date_time">02, Thu</span>
        </label>
    </div>
<div class="form-check sc_click">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="date[]" value="2023-03-02">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="timeslot[]" value="18" id="18">
        <label class="form-check-label d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center" for="18">
            <span> 11:00 AM - 01:00 PM (2 Hour)</span>
            <span class="ic_date_time">02, Thu</span>
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

if i check one checkbox its check top date[] array checkbox is checked

Comment: give different names to your checkbox. By default same named checkboxes share the same state ( easy way to explain it ).

Answer (score 0):

**you can check this**

```
function checkOtherCheckbox() {
  var checkboxA = document.getElementById("checkboxA");
  var checkboxB = document.getElementById("checkboxB");
  
  if (checkboxA.checked) {
    checkboxB.checked = true;
  } else {
    checkboxB.checked = false;
  }
}
```